# My read() is returning -1, but i cant see why?? TCP socket programming in C

Tags: c, sockets, server, tcp, client

I am doing an assignment where we code a server and client that use a TCP stream socket to transfer file name, file size, etc.
I have the code for the server and client, and it currently sends the file name size, file name, and the file size successfully, but when the data for the actual file is sent the client reads and sends all the data, but the server only loops once and reads "-1 bytes from network". text

```
//server code
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

//function declaration
int readfile(FILE *inputFile, FILE *outputFile);


//main function
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    typedef char* bufferPtr;

    int sd; /* socket descriptor */
    int connected_sd; /* socket descriptor */
    int rc; /* return code from recvfrom */
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;
    struct sockaddr_in from_address;
    socklen_t fromLength;

    char nameBuffer[100];
    unsigned char fileBuffer[1000];
    int portNumber;
    int ACK = 0;

    FILE * outputFile;

    //function to make sure port number is given
    if (argc < 2){
        printf ("Usage is: server <portNumber>\n");
        exit (1);
    }

    //needed for server/socket configuration
    portNumber = atoi(argv[1]);
    sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    fromLength = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    rc = bind (sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(server_address));

    //function to make sure it binds properly
    if (rc < 0){
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    //loop to contniue listening for a connection
    do{
        //listen for connection and connect
        listen (sd, 5);
        connected_sd = accept (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from_address, &fromLength);
        memset(nameBuffer, 0, 100);

        //variables needed for file name size and the file size 
        int fileNameSize;
        int fileSize;
        int* fileNameSizePtr = &fileNameSize;
        int* fileSizePtr = &fileSize;


        rc = read(connected_sd, fileNameSizePtr, sizeof(int));
        printf("Read %d bytes to get the size of the file name\n", rc);

        fileNameSize = ntohs(fileNameSize);

        // variables for reading filename from network
        int totalBytesRead = 0;
        char * nameBuffPtr = nameBuffer;

        //read filename
        while(totalBytesRead < fileNameSize){
            rc = read(connected_sd, nameBuffPtr, fileNameSize-totalBytesRead);
        if(rc == -1){
        if(errno == EINTR){
            printf("interrupted signal\n");
            break;
        }
        else if(errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK){
            printf("no data to read\n");
            break;
        }
        }
            if(rc < 0){
                exit(1);
            }
            totalBytesRead += rc;
            nameBuffPtr += rc;
        }
        printf("Received file name %s\n", nameBuffer);

        //read the size of the file and convert to proper endianness
        rc = read(connected_sd, fileSizePtr, sizeof(int));

        //reset total bytes read for file data reading
        totalBytesRead = 0;
        int numberOfBytes;
        unsigned char * fileBufferPtr = fileBuffer;

    if((outputFile = fopen(nameBuffer, "wb")) ==NULL){
                exit(1);
        }

        while(totalBytesRead < fileSize){
        printf("%d\n", fileSize);
            rc = read(connected_sd, fileBufferPtr, fileSize);
        if(rc == -1){
            if(errno == EINTR){
                printf("interrupted signal\n");
            }
            if(errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK){
                printf("no data\n");}}
            numberOfBytes = rc;
            printf("read %d bytes from network\n", rc);
            
            if(rc < 0){
                exit(1);
            }

            
            rc = fwrite(&fileBuffer, 1, numberOfBytes, outputFile);

            fileBufferPtr += rc;
            totalBytesRead += rc;
            printf("Progress: %d bytes\n", totalBytesRead);

            if(totalBytesRead == fileSize){
                printf("All data received\n");
                    ACK = ntohs(1);
                    rc = write(connected_sd, &ACK, sizeof(int));
            }
        }

    }while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

```
//client code
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BUFFSIZE 1000

int readfile(FILE *inputFile, int socket);
int getFileLength(FILE* fp);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sd;
    int portNumber;
    int rc = 0;
    char serverIP[29];
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;

    int fileNameSize;
    int fileSize;
    char fileName[100];
    char done[] = "DONE";
    FILE *inputFile;


    if (argc < 3){
        printf ("usage is client <ipaddr> <port>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    portNumber = atoi(argv[2]);
    strcpy(serverIP, argv[1]);
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(portNumber);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverIP);

    if(connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0) {
        close(sd);
        perror("error connecting stream socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    //loop until user enters "DONE"
    do{

        //ask for file name
        printf("Enter the filename: \n");
        scanf("%s", fileName);

        //calculate the size of the file name and send it to server
        fileNameSize = strlen(fileName);
        fileNameSize = ntohs(fileNameSize);
        rc = write(sd, &fileNameSize, sizeof(fileNameSize));
        
        //wrtie the name of the file to the server
        int bytesToWrite = ntohs (fileNameSize);
        rc = write(sd, &fileName, bytesToWrite);

        printf("wrote %d bytes to send the filename\n", rc);

        //open file to be read
        if((inputFile = fopen(fileName, "rb")) == NULL){
            printf("Error opening the file %s\n", fileName);
            exit(1);
        }

        fileSize = getFileLength(inputFile);
        printf("%D\n", fileSize);

        //fileSize = ntohs (fileSize);
        rc = write(sd, &fileSize, sizeof(int));
        printf("%d\n", rc);

        readfile(inputFile, sd);


    }while(strcmp(fileName, done) != 0);

    return 0;
}


int readfile(FILE *inputFile, int socket){
    unsigned char buffer [BUFFSIZE];
    int numberOfBytes;
    int rc;
    int totalBytesRead=0, totalBytesWritten=0;

    numberOfBytes = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFSIZE, inputFile);

    while (numberOfBytes > 0){
        totalBytesRead += numberOfBytes;
        
        rc = write (socket, buffer, numberOfBytes);
        if (numberOfBytes != rc){
            perror ("writing to server");
            exit(1); }
        totalBytesWritten += rc; 
        printf("%d\n", totalBytesWritten);
        numberOfBytes = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFSIZE, inputFile);
    }
    printf ("read %d bytes, and wrote %d bytes\n", totalBytesRead,
totalBytesWritten);
return (0); 
}

int getFileLength(FILE* fp)
{
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int len = (int) ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    return len;
}
```

I can't tell what the issue is. Sometimes when I use print statements to debug, the amount of data read and written changes from the client and server side.

Comment: If `read()` returns -1 then that means an error occurred.  `errno` will contain information about the nature of the error.  `perror()` will print a human-readable error message to `stderr`.

Comment: Tip: You're not going to get EINTR if you don't setup any signal handlers. You can remove these checks.

Comment: Tip: You're not going to get EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK if you don't make the socket non-blocking. You can remove these checks.

Comment: Tip: Error messages should be sent to stderr, not stdout. Use `fprintf( stderr, ... )` instead of `printf( ... )`. (`perror` does send to stderr. That's all good.)

Comment: You are misusing `ntohs()`.  For a 16-bit unsigned (or at least non-negative) value, the sender uses **`htons()`** to change the data from its own byte order to network byte order, and the receiver uses `ntohs()` to convert to *its* own byte order.  You're using `ntohs()` on both sides.  Moreover, your `int` is probably 32-bits wide, in which case you should be using `ntohl()` and `htonl()`, instead.

Comment: Im getting a segmentation fault, but I am still lost. My server continues the loop and reads 1000 bytes before reading another 1000 and getting a segmentation fault.

Comment: I guess you mean that you changed something, and now the modified program segfaults instead of failing in `read()`.  A segfault generally means that the program tried to access memory that does not belong to it.  This is a good candidate for causing such a thing: `read(connected_sd, fileBufferPtr, fileSize)` when `fileSize` is larger than the size of `fileBuffer`.

Comment: I tried making fileBuffer larger, but the file is too big the server segfaults immediately. I intended to use "read(connected_sd, fileBufferPtr, fileSize)" to read only 1000 bytes of data at a time, which is how much the client is sending at a time. What am i missing?

Comment: Also, after reading the next 1000 bytes, the program goes into the "if(rc < 0){exit(1);}" , except my new code has "exit(1)" replaced with "perror("errno"):" which is where the segfault msg comes from

Comment: I think i see the issue, whatever size fileBuffer is, that is how many bytes the server is able to read from the network. How would i go about implementing what i mentioned above? The client sends 1000 bytes at a time and the server receives 1000 bytes at a time, writing it to the outputFile. Even after changing fileBuffer to 1.5mb, the server reads all the data but fails to write it to the outputFile. (outputFile is created in the folder though)

Comment: Assuming that a TCP read of sizeof(int) will always read sizeof(int) bytes is a really bad plan:)